# Executing a batch file on a remote server

Tags: php, windows, batch-file, cmd, ffmpeg

I have an IIS server with Php and have been trying to execute scripts using exec() and system() with no luck. When i go to the machine and run it by double clicking it, or by opening command and running the batch file, 4 windows pop open with ffmpeg streams going and dump to folder.

With `exec("cmd.exe 'c:\inetpub\wwwroot\estf\batch\srRecord.bat'");`
I am getting some of the batch file process working (creates new folder and dumps to file, but i can't see the cmd gui anywhere. And my stop.bat won't taskkill the ffmpeg process.

Is there a way to bring up the cmd GUI on the external device, also a way to run the exec() command and pass on so that other devices or batch files can kill these tasks (i am thinking that because the php is still running it, nothing else has rights to stop it.

Regards,

Mitchell

Comment: The cmd is executed under the user running IIS, not the logged in user so nothing will appear. Opening a cmd on the client looks like a security hole (not sure if even possible).

Comment: Your command line is wrong. Type `cmd /?` to see what you omitted.

Comment: Sory i have tried "cmd.exe /c 'path'", but no luck. So i am not trying to open a cmd on the client, i am trying to open it back on the server that has IIS. I know i have gotten it to kind of run but there is no GUI and becuase the php script is still waiting for the batch to finish, the page won't fully load, and i can't stop the batch any other way as it is still being run by the php page (it is a video recording of ffmpeg and keeps going until another batch file kills it. ACatinLove, any suggestions on the correct code?